# I can't read the return of built-in help() in python... Because the notation of documentation can't be understood

Tags: python, python-2.7

TBH I'm beginner in learning python but I'm working well when it's come to reading the man page of Linux and the notation/conventin of it 
Such as 
-- bold text is type exactly as shown in synopsis
-- italic text replaced with the appropriate argument 
-- [-abc] all of this are optional 
.... Etc are in **man man** command

But how I can read the synopsis that return from **help('smething')**

Answer (score 0):

Just type help(), then enter and type 'smething'